# How to store instructions in database?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm creating a site, where each product has different types of instructions.
For example, product A has instructions:

```
1) Step 1....

2) Step 2....

etc
```

How would I store these instructions in the database?
My current database structure is as follows :

`| ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | ETC |`

Comment: As always in database design: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to save the steps in one big text blob, you can add a steps column in your table. If you want them as separate steps, make a steps table and have a steps_id in your existing table.

Comment: I think i got the idea of it. Thanks for the help !